# How to regex match exactly two timestamps separated by any number of newlines and/or text

Tags: python, regex

I have a basic timestamp regex that matches one or two digits followed by colon then two digits:

```
r"(\s?\d{1,2}\:\d{2})"
```

Now I want to check whether a string contains exactly two timestamps separated by text and newlines, e.g.

```
1:23 asdf \n 1:23.
```

Comment: To match the timestamp pattern until the next timestamp pattern on a new line you might try `^\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!.*\b\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\b).*)*\r?\n.*\b\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\b` See https://regex101.com/r/MRfqDw/1 If there can be no 2 timestamps on a single line, try this longer pattern https://regex101.com/r/wPEiRE/1

Answer (score 0):

sequence = """
1:23

asdf 
1:23
"""

pattern = r"(\d:\d{2})\D+(\d:\d{2})"

match = re.search(pattern, sequence)
print(match.groups())